# Why do empty objects appear in OC array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I assign one array to another, I get an error, as shown in [P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHzLP.jpg).

Then I checked the contents of _carIDArray and found an empty object in it. It was this object that caused the crash.[P2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpLm9.jpg)

Why do empty objects appear in arrays? When using addobjcet: will not the array crash?

Here's some codes related to _carIDArray:

```
CarModel *car = [[CarModel alloc] initWithStatusAndMsgWithDic:object];

if (!_carIdArray) {
    _carIdArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
if (car.carIdStr && car.carIdStr.length>0){     
    [_carIdArray addObject:car.carIdStr];
}
```

*object is the data from the server.

```
@interface CarModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *carIdStr;
@end
```

Comment: There are ArrayTypes that can hold nil objects. NSArray and NSMutableArray can't because nil is terminating the array after the lastObject. You could check for nil before adding the Object

Comment: It seems you check right so I suspect carIdStr is a ```weak``` pointer somehow. But you need to work hard to make it weak, so maybe show ```[CarModel carIdStr]``` message?

Comment: Hmmmmmm ... NSMutableArray should keep a strong pointer but coming from the server I suspect there are some funny stuff and you need to copy the server data somehow or change the property to be ```strong```

Comment: In other words, what will happen when `[[CarModel alloc] initWithStatusAndMsgWithDic:nil]` or the dictionary you use to init CarModel is incomplete?

Comment: Yes inspector, well spotted ... ```object``` is probably where the trouble is ... show us how you instantiate ```object``` and how you init ```CarModel``` with it please.

Comment: Thanks for all! There are some codes:  -(void)getCarStatusAddMsgWithDic:(NSDictionary *)dic{
    self.carId=[[dic objectForKey:@"carId"] longValue];
    .....
}

Comment: -(void)setCarId:(long)carId{
    _carId=carId;
    self.carIdStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",carId];
}

Comment: I think "carId" of dic is kind of NSString.

Comment: This one is still bugging me - how can nil end up in mutable array ... I was thinking maybe the carId is 0 but that screenshot shows the object itself is nil ... I think *maybe* it is a concurrency issue ... it is difficult without more code to tell.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer to the question. The objects in the array may be released after being added to the array.